# Splat on a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.9, null, splat

- A splat on a hash converts it into an array.

  `[*{foo: :bar}] # => [[:foo, :bar]]`

  Is there some hidden mechanism (such as implicit class cast) going on here, or is it a built-in primitive feature?
- Besides an array, are `nil` and hash the only things that disappear/change with the splat operator under Ruby 1.9?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A splat will attempt an explicit conversion of an object to an Array.

To do this, it will send `to_a` and expect an `Array` as a result.

```
class Foo
  def to_a
    [1,2,3]
  end
end

a, b, c = *Foo.new
a # => 1
```

If the object does not respond to `to_a`, then there is no effect, e.g. `[*42] == [42]`

Many builtin classes implement `to_a`. In particular:

- (because they include `Enumerable`)

  - `Array`
  - `Hash`
  - `Range`
  - `IO` and `File`
  - `Enumerator`
  - `Enumerator::Lazy` (Ruby 2.0)
  - `Set` and `SortedSet`
- (additional classes)

  - `NilClass`
  - `MatchData`
  - `OpenStruct`
  - `Struct`
  - `Time`
  - `Matrix` and `Vector`

All these can thus be splatted:

```
match, group, next_group = *"Hello, world".match(/(.*), (.*)/)
group # => "Hello"
```

Comment: Splatted `nil` disappears Under Ruby 1.9, and this does not fit the case of there being no effect, so this is the only exception, I guess. Am I right?

Comment: Oh, forgot about `nil`. Edited answer. `NilClass` implements `to_a` (by returning `[]`), so it's not a special case. No effect would mean that `[*nil]` would be `[nil]` instead of `[]`