# Passing splat on nil as argument

Tags: ruby, arguments, null, splat

All values for `b` below let me call a method with the `*args` syntax.

```
def some_method(a)
   puts a
end

b = 1
some_method(*b) # => 1

b = false
some_method(*b) # => false

b = "whatever"
some_method(*b) # => "whatever"
```

With `nil`, I expected to get `nil`, not argument error:

```
b = nil
some_method(*b) # => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Interestingly this breaks referential transparency, try doing `b = *nil; method(b)` which works fine.

Comment: On a less related note, I'd get nervous of calling a method `method`. it does spooky things to my `pry` (starts printing `:inspect`). I'm assuming you wouldn't do it normally but I thought it was interesting so I thought I'd mention it, I'd be interested if someone could tell me what is causing that.

Comment: Well, I don't think I can really do that. The thing is that I am doing some meta-programming where the stuff that goes through could be _any_ value, including nil, but possibly array. So I kind of need it to be `method(*b)`. And yes, the name "method" for a method is not good. Was just an example here.

Comment: I suspect it can have something with nil not being a proper object or something. But would be nice to know.

Comment: I agree it would be nice to know, which is why I want to keep an eye on the question (and why I upvoted you), but you can eliminate this problem in this one case by having an extra line saying `b= *b` as this will coerce `nil` into `[]` and will leave arrays the same.

Comment: Ahh, so do `b= *b; some_method(*b)`? That could work.

Comment: Yep, I'm not gonna post it as an answer as it doesn't answer the question (of what dark magic has infected ruby's `nil`) but it is at least a solution. :)

Comment: I think `b = [] if b == nil` would be more clear and better actually, but yeah. What is going on with nil?

Comment: @MikeH-R: There is already [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-method) so calling your own method `method` won't work out so well.

Comment: @muistooshort I did that mistake in my original question if you check the history.

Comment: @muistooshort agreed. I just don't understand what exactly it's doing under the hood. I would expect it to override the default method with the one we've defined. What I don't get is that in my pry it starts printing `:inspect` every time a string is printed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The splat operator `*` first applies `to_a` to the object if it is not an array and `to_a` is defined on it. For numerals, falseclass, and strings, `to_a` is not defined, and they remain themselves. For nilclass, `to_a` is defined and returns an empty array. When they are splatted, the numerals, falseclass, and strings remain themselves, but the empty array becomes absence of anything. Also see an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303499/splat-on-a-hash).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Nice to know the proper name for it. Found some [docs on ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html).